# thread 1: signal SIGABRT mysterious error

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, xcode6, sigabrt

when i run my app in the simulator, everything functions out perfectly until i select a button which is to segue into my main table view, the app crashes and gives me the SIGABRT error. the console shows nothing but (lldb)

here is my MainTableViewController coding:

```
import UIKit

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myVariable = ["LIST OF STRINGS"]

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myVariable.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var SuperVariable= myVariable[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = SuperVariable
        return cell
    }
}
```

all my storyboard segues have identifiers as well. what is the issue?? :/

Comment: Is your segue correct? Put a break point in this class and check wether control is coming to this class? Also replace the cell intialisation line with         let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
 and try.

Comment: Robert, I would make sure that the scene's tableview has a prototype cell with a storyboard identifier equal to that `reuseIdentifier`. (And I respectfully disagree with Amit89's suggestion, though: It may eliminate the crash (and confirm what the problem was), but it's not the right approach. It's better to fix the root problem, the cell prototype.)

Comment: THANKS! that was the issue. :} - @Rob